# How do i correctly iterate over a JSON in DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I have the following data:

```
{ 
    "0":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"7",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"13",
            "DPD":"13",
            "DA":"7",
            "DPD2":"7",
            "PATTERN":"+"
        }
    ],
    "1":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"15",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"-3",
            "DPD":"-16",
            "DA":"-1",
            "DPD2":"-8",
            "PATTERN":"+"
        }
    ],
    "2":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"31",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"-35",
            "DPD":"32",
            "DA":"-17",
            "DPD2":"16",
            "PATTERN":"+"
        }
    ],
    "3":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"63",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"-99",
            "DPD":"64",
            "DA":"-49",
            "DPD2":"32",
            "PATTERN":"+"
        }
    ],
    "4":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"127",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"-227",
            "DPD":"128",
            "DA":"-113",
            "DPD2":"64",
            "PATTERN":"+"
        }
    ],
    "5":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"255",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"-483",
            "DPD":"256",
            "DA":"-241",
            "DPD2":"128",
            "PATTERN":"+"
        }
    ],
    "6":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"511",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"-995",
            "DPD":"512",
            "DA":"-497",
            "DPD2":"256",
            "PATTERN":"+"
        }
    ],
    "7":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"1023",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"29",
            "DPD":"-1024",
            "DA":"15",
            "DPD2":"-512",
            "PATTERN":"-"
        }
    ],
    "8":[ 
        { 
            "Y":"2047",
            "J":"1038",
            "DOUBLIN":"-2019",
            "DPD":"-2048",
            "DA":"-1009",
            "DPD2":"-1024",
            "PATTERN":"-"
        }
    ]
}
```

I used this code in my html which I get from `ip = response.json()` in `views.py`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>HERE SERIOUSLY</h2>
  {% for i in ip %}

       <p>Your data is <strong>{{ i }}</strong></p>

  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But the output is the first numbers only, I need to access all the data. When I try `i.Y`, it's blank and I expect the first one to be 7.

Here's the output:

```
Your Data is 0
Your Data is 1
Your Data is 2
Your Data is 3
Your Data is 4
Your Data is 5
Your Data is 6
Your Data is 7
Your Data is 8
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to correctly iterate over my json so I can build a `<td>` table from all the data inside each item?

ANSWERED, i changed my code to:

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>HERE SERIOUSLY</h2>
{% for i, data in ip.items %}
  {% for x in data %}
    <p>Your data is <strong>{{ i }} {{ data.0 }}</strong></p>
    <p>Your x in data is {{ x }}</p>
    <p>Your x.Y in data is {{ x.Y }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

and was able to access the individual attributes. Thanks to everyone especially Selcuk for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ip` is a `dict`, you must use `.items` to access both keys and values:

```
{% for index, data in ip.items %}
  <p>Your data #{{ index }} is <strong>{{ data }}</strong></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Since `data` is a single item `list` itself, you must get the first (`0`th) element and use the following syntax to access items:

```
{{ data.0.DOUBLIN }}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to order my data so i don't have to use the number each time, i really want to iterate over this programmatically as i don't know the size of the data each time. I updated my question with a recent suggested edit to show my json better.

Comment: If it is possible to have more than one item in `data`, you should have a second `for` loop as in `{% for item in data %}` then simply use `{{ item.DOUBLIN }}`.

Answer (score 0):

To access `"Y"` we can do:

```
<p>Your data is <strong>{{ ip.i.0.Y }}</strong></p>
```

In the first iteration, when `i = "0"`:

- `ip.i` gives `[{"Y":"7","J":"1038","DOUBLIN":"13","DPD":"13","DA":"7","DPD2":"7","PATTERN":"+"}]`.
- `ip.i.0` gives `{"Y":"7","J":"1038","DOUBLIN":"13","DPD":"13","DA":"7","DPD2":"7","PATTERN":"+"}`.
- `ip.i.0.Y` gives `"7"`.

---

A more elegant way of doing it is to use `items`:

```
{% for i, data in ip.items %}
    <p>Your data is <strong>{{ i }} {{ data.0.Y }}</strong></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: for some reason django errors on me when i use indexing with [], i have to use data.0 or data.0.y, but in this case it's just coming up blank, is there a way to iterate over the data in data as well, so i can access them like data.Y, data.J, data.PATTERN, etc?

Comment: Yes, an alternative is to use `data.0.Y`. Please try it.

Comment: @DipenDadhaniya It is not an alternative, it is the only way. Square bracket indexing is not supported by Django. Your first method (`ip.i...`) won't work at all as you can't use variable indexes either. Please don't post answers to questions without testing to see if they work first.